# How to consume Azure Alert payload to HTTP trigger azure function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-alerts

I am trying to consume the payload that azure alert is sending while calling an Azure function.

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    req_body = req.get_json()
    print(req_body)
```

but not getting anything in req_body variable.
Anyone on how to consume it in python azure function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use azure alert to trigger Azure Function, please refer to the following steps

1. Create Azure Function. My code is as below

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

  
    req_body = req.get_json()
    logging.info(req_body)
    return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
    )
```

2. Create alert

   a. Define condition

   b. Define action group
   [image]
3. Test
   [image]